# How do I handle NA values in R for raster layer with datatype INT2U?

Tags: r, raster, missing-data, geotiff

I have raster layers from geotiff files with datatype INT2U, aka unsigned short. The original data, floating point, were encoded by multiplying by 100 and then rounding to both reduce file size and to facilitate quick display with software that didn't work with floating point values.

I need to extract the original data by dividing the raster values by 100.  The problem is that the value 65535 was used by the software that geo-rectified the original data.  When asking the raster what the NA value I get 'negative infinity' and INT2U values are all positive.  The result is that the 65535 values are treated as valid values not NA. 65535 is the larger integer possible as an unsigned int.

```
> r <- rasters[[1]]
> NAvalue(r)
[1] -Inf
> maxValue(r)
[1] 65535
> minValue(r)
[1] 0
> r1 <- r/100
> maxValue(r1)
[1] 655.34
> NAvalue(r)
[1] -Inf
```

I have some code to check that a value is valid, that is its not in the corners of the image - the aircraft was flying NE to SW so after the images are geo-rectified the pixels in the corners of the resulting images are not valid data.

How can I decomm (restore the original data) setting the 65535 values to the standard NA?

Comment: Please post example data in a format that can be readily copy-pasted and worked with (e.g. as the output from ```dput()```.

Comment: @rjen I'll be happy do do that but need some guidance. How do I create a vector of unsigned integers in R?

Comment: Have a look at `?raster::Which, cells =TRUE` to index, or cells=FALSE  your -inf and 65535 as a logical mask layer.

Comment: If I understood your request correctly, you only have to write the following line of code : `r[r == 65535] <- NA` (if necessary, you can save your original raster by entering the following line of code before :  `r_save <- r`)

Comment: @lovalery You do understand my question but your answer doesn't work for INT2U!  While continuing to analyze I found a very few other values above 65000, the highest valid value is around 1500 in this particular raster so those values are noise and not NA, but they should be.  I can change all values  above 65000 to 0 which is not a valid value but it does simplify some other code that examines values. I think that your answer would have worked if the data type were INt2S. I'll probably delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-up to your comment @Nate Lockwood, the problem is not with the "INT2U" format. I have just prepared a small REPREX (see below) which shows that you can assign the value NA to a raster in INT2U format without any problem.

To be honest, I don't know where the problem you are experiencing comes from, but the cause is most likely something else.

Hope this will contribute to help you a little to find the origin of the problem, though.

**REPREX:**

```r
library(raster)
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : sp
# Creating a raster
r <- raster(ncols = 3, nrows = 3)
(values(r) <- seq(length(r)))
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
dataType(r)
#> [1] "FLT4S"
# Converting to INT2U format
r_convert <- tempfile("raster", fileext = ".tif")

writeRaster(r, r_convert, datatype = "INT2U", overwrite = TRUE)
r_INT2U <- raster(r_convert)

# Checking format of r_INT2u
dataType(r_INT2U)
#> [1] "INT2U"
# Creating object rc_INT2U to keep the original raster object 'r_INT2U'
rc_INT2U <- r_INT2U

rc_INT2U[rc_INT2U == 9] <- NA

values(rc_INT2U)
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm marking your answer as  solved because it would have led me to the real cause of my problem: some kind of noise in some of the data.  I did figure that out on my own,  unaware of the technique you provided, and that is worth saving.  I now know that at least one of the 111 data files did have at least one real NA which I handled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice reply. I am glad to hear that you have succeeded in finding the solution to your problem. I wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

But there is nothing difficult about it. Just set a new value of `NAvalue` by simple assignment.
See this example.

```
library(raster)

r1 <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
NAvalue(r1)
#[1] -3.4e+38
plot(r1)
```

As you can see for `r1`, the value of `NAValue` is `-3.4e + 38`.

[image]
Well, let's change it to e.g. 200

```
NAvalue(r1) = 200
NAvalue(r1)
#[1] 200
plot(r1)
```

[image]

And that's all. Hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work with data type INT2U which are all 16 bit unsigned integers, no negative numbers.  See my comment above.